# seting up a template folder copy/ past system with batch

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory

I have a foldering system setup consisting  of a “master folder” wich varys in name holds two sub folders, the sub folders though are always called CTB and DWG. I want the contents. of the DWG folder always to be coppied to the desktop and the contents of the CTB to always be coppied to C:\ICT\Autocad_2010\CTB. Remembering that the master folder varys in name pending on the project.

Is this possible with batch?

somthing like:

```
XCOPY %0\DWG\*.* c:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\CTB
```

Nevermind i got it

```
XCOPY "%cd%\DWG\*.DWG" c:\
```

however how do i copy it to the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

try this to copy to the current user desktop

```
xcopy "dwg\*.dwg" "%Homedrive%%Homepath%\desktop"
```

or this to copy to all users desktop

```
xcopy "dwg\*.dwg" "%allusersprofile%\desktop"
```

Comment: `%Homedrive%%Homepath%` = `%USERPROFILE%`.